# The gridlayout vgap changes on its own, how can I make it always the same?

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, grid-layout

I am making a messaging app where a server and a client communicate with each other by sending messages. I have a main panel where the messages are printed, and it is set with gridlayout and put on a scrollpane, but every time I send or receive a message the vgap gets from large to smaller until a certain point where it becomes always the same.
Here is the code:

```
static JPanel messagesPanel = new JPanel();

public void crea(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame("ItMessenger lato server");
    f.setSize(400,750);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Font tit = new Font("Roboto", Font.BOLD, 20);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel messaggio = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    JPanel chat = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel contatto = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    f.add(p);
    p.add(messaggio, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    p.add(chat, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    p.add(contatto, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel c = new JLabel("Contatto Client");
    c.setFont(tit);
    c.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    contatto.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    int width = f.getWidth();
    int height = f.getHeight();

    contatto.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, (int)(height * 0.10)));
    chat.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, (int)(height * 0.75)));
    messaggio.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, (int)(height * 0.15)));

    contatto.setBackground(new Color(0,128,105,255));

    messagesPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,0,0));

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(messagesPanel);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
    chat.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JTextField text = new JTextField("Messaggio");
    text.setDocument(new LimitedDocument(44));
    text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,75));
    //  Il FocusListener fa in modo che se si clicca la JTextField, la scritta per indicare la casella del messaggio sparisce
    text.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            if (text.getText().equals("Messaggio")) {
                text.setText("");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            if (text.getText().isEmpty()) {
                text.setText("Messaggio");
            }
        }
    });
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10); // margine a sinistra e destra
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    messaggio.add(text, gbc);

    ImageIcon sendIcon = new ImageIcon(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource("send64.png")));
    JButton invia = new JButton(sendIcon);
    invia.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sendIcon.getIconWidth(), sendIcon.getIconHeight()));
    invia.setBorderPainted(false);
    invia.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    invia.setFocusPainted(false);
    invia.setOpaque(false);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    messaggio.add(invia, gbc);
    messaggio.add(invia);

    invia.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) ->{
        String message = text.getText();
        if(!Objects.equals(message, "")) {
            JPanel cont = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

            RoundedPanel messagePanel = new RoundedPanel(20);
            messagePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            messagePanel.setBackground(new Color(231, 255, 219, 255));
            JLabel l = new JLabel(message);
            l.setFont(mex);
            messagePanel.add(l);
            cont.add(messagePanel);
            messagesPanel.add(cont);
            messagesPanel.revalidate();
            text.setText("Messaggio");
            ss.scrivi(message);
        }
    });

    text.addActionListener(e -> {
        invia.doClick();
        text.setText("");
    });

    f.setVisible(true);
    ts.start();
}
```

That's when I send two messages and the vgap is large:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUwIm.png]

Instead that's when I send many messages and the gap becomes always the same :
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKyg4.png]

I expect the vgap between messages to always be fixed from the beginning

Comment: [mcve] please  .. and: as a general rule, don't hard-code sizing hints

Comment: That is eactly the way GridLayout works. Each component has an equal size in the space available.  One solution is to use a "wrapper panel" to create the scroll pane. The wrapper panel can use a BorderLayout. Add the 'messagesPanel" to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START, of the wrapper panel, which will respect the height of components added.